# JavaScript DOM Window

Tags: javascript

Ok so if I create a window in JavaScript and the parent page changes like to a search page how can I handle the popup window from the page before?

Comment: Handle, I mean like alter information inside, when I open a window from a button it opens a window and in the window a user would search and then click go, well this search changes the URL in the parent window and therefore looses the variable so how can I re declare the variable so I can alter the information inside the window with the search results (This is how my client wants it)

Comment: Take note: the language is "JavaScript", not "java-script"

Comment: How about to use an inner frame to the navigation?

Answer (score 1):

Just call [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) with the same name (second parameter). It will give you back that window instance if it's still open instead of opening a new one.

Comment: But it refreshes it rather then let me control it.

Comment: It will let you control it, but you will lose it's previous state. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'handle'?

However if you want to add content, close the window, give it focus, etc look at the Window Object Methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window

Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to do or are try to achieve?

Comment: Please consider linking to MDC instead and refraining from linking to W3Schools. MDC is a better resource.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window

Comment: @Xeon06 - My bad, I agree MDC is better, will refrain from linking to W3Schools

Comment: Handle, I mean like alter information inside, when I open a window from a button it opens a window and in the window a user would search and then click go, well this search changes the URL in the parent window and therefore looses the variable so how can I re declare the variable so I can alter the information inside the window with the search results (This is how my client wants it)

Comment: @WebOD-Bradley - Can you provide some code or put this on jsFiddle?